# How to get default value of the field in Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

I am getting all required fields (Standard & Custom) through the following RESTlet file function name **getFields**.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ganeshprabhus/68a9e5b81e53436bb1d684f857a6c31f/raw/67fe03895f1c31d65c1f283dd51584af45d27c59/NS_Script_2016.2004

I could get fields' type and label. i want to get the default value of the field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
field_details['Value'] = record.getFieldValue(fieldName);
field_details['Text'] = record.getFieldText(fieldName);
```

to pull the value and display text of those fields off the record object.  Running that through on a customer record will give you results like this:

```
customform = {object}
Type = {string} select
Label = {string} Custom Form
Value = {number} 23
Text = {string} XX Customer Form
```

Comment: If you know , could you tell me how to get Max length of the field and reference link